# Sorting a map<list<list<int>>,int> by sum of keyvalue

Tags: c++, maps

I have a `map<list<list<int>>,int>` and I wish to sort the map based on the sum of the elements in the list in descending order in C++. For example if initially the contents of my map look like:-

```
{1,0}->38
{1,19}->1
{1,21}->1
{2,0}->5
{2,12}->1
```

Finally the result I am aiming to achieve is

```
{1,0}->38
{2,0}->5
{2,12}->1
{1,19}->1
{1,21}->1
```

Comment: You'll need to create a custom comparator for the map.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe looks like a `list<int>`. Not `list<list<int>>`

You can specify a comparator class for your map that would define the order of elements as you wish.

In your case:

```
map< list<int>, int, list_cmp >;

struct list_cmp {
  bool operator() ( const list<int>& lhs, const list<int>& rhs ) {
    // using > instead of < to get descending order
    return std::accumulate(lhs.begin(),lhs.end(),0) > std::accumulate(rhs.begin(),rhs.end(),0)
  }
};
```

This is obviously sub-optimal. You should consider caching the sum. You can wrap the `list<int>` in your own class with a `sum` member.

Also, you might want to use a `multimap` if you can have both `{1,3}` and `{2,2}` keys.

One last point - a map is sorting (and rebalancing etc) on insertion. If you want to sort once, you may use a vector and call sort once after populating it. The comperator would be the same.